# Return to previous page on exact point in React

Tags: reactjs, navigation, anchor

Imagine I have page A with very long list of rows. I scroll down to e.g. row number 500. The row is also link to page B, that shows row details. After examinig the details on page B, I want to go back to page A, but I want to return to exactly same point, from where I went to page B, that means on the row 500. How can I achieve this behavior in ReactJS app?

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved in two ways.

1. One simple use of html id attributes.
2. With the help of react-router-dom and props passing.

I have listed the method 1 here which is beginner friendly

This can be achieved with the help of id's
I will list a sample html code which works similar at jsx

```html
<div>
<p id="1">Row 1 </p>
<p id="2">Row 2 </p>
...
...
...
</div>
```

Let's suppose the use of the page is `www.samplepage.com`
Instead of this link if I made it specific i.e., `www.samplepage.com#1`
it will take me to the **Row 1** it is like anchor tag in same page
you can store the tags in state and use it.

You can also see similar implementation at github

Comment: Thank you. I´d really prefer the "react" solution. Can you please explain, how to achieve this kind of navigation with react-router-dom?

Answer (score 0):

First pass your current path with query parameter

```
<Link to={{pathname: `/apps/calendar`, query: `/apps/personnel/view/${selectedPersonnel.id}`}} >
```

Second use this parameter in redirected component with following code

```
const CalendarComponent = props => {
   const backUrl = props.location['query']
}
```